# remove top panel bar Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mate, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

I'm trying to remove top bar panel from Ubuntu mate for raspberry pi. I tried so many things but any works for me. I remove mate desktop to try install ubuntu desktop but no works anymore.

Because of this i reinstall ubuntu mate, and now i continue try to remove top bar. I need to run my app at startup in fullscreen mode withou any bar to acess system.
Thanks

Comment: Look it: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2355048

Comment: This is just for two bars. I just have one and don't have `delete panel`

Answer (score 2):

By default, Mate don't allow to delete the last panel. Anyway, if you wish to run apps in fullscreen, you should enable autohide option in panel :
Right on panel > properties > untick expand and tick autohide.

Comment: In this case it is possible to see the panel. So, I remove all icons, enable autohide and put panel transparent. Now it's ok, but I thing that should have a better way to do this.